# "No input file specified" - unable to access phpMyAdmin using debian squeeze

Tags: apache-2.2

I have installed phpMyAdmin on my VPS LAMP server (Debian Squeeze/Apache2/MySQL/PHP5), but am unable to access it: //my-ip/phpmyadmin/ and //my-domain/phpmyadmin/ both produce the following error message: "No input file specified".

The [phpMyAdmin FAQ](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) identifies this as a permission problem, but the suggested solution seems not to apply to my situation. Every other solution I have come across involves removing/purging and reinstalling phpmyadmin - which I have done several times, always to the same result. [Previous posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/521298/cant-get-access-to-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-under-debian-no-input-file-specified) in this forum typically relate to Nginx, which I have not installed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: maybe a dumb question, does "/etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup" exist?

Comment: It does, with "admin" as sole user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now found the solution to my problem. The error log revealed a fastCGI-error:

```
FastCGI: server "/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi" stderr: Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php (No such file or directory)
```

However, the file did exist, and according to [another serverfault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/459237/nginx-php-no-input-file-specified-for-1-server-block-other-server-block-wor) this could be due to the doc_root parameter in php.ini. Commenting out doc_root resolved the issue (I had it set to /var/www). Hopefully, this may be useful to other forum readers.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is kinda outdated, but today I had the same problem. And my solution was to create a symlink link between `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` and `/var/www/html`

The folder phpMyAdmin was missing in the `www` folder so I was not able not find the correct files for phpMyAdmin!

And don't forget to have a look in the logs files of Apache sometimes.